# Decrease /boot size on Fedora 23

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, fedora, grub

I have a problem with my `/boot` partition. It only has 200 MB which is insufficient - it is almost full.

I have already unistalled old kernels (via `dnf`, keeping only the latest one) but there are still some files on `/boot` which are obviously related to the old (removed) kernels:

- `config-*`
- `initramfs-*`
- `System.map-*`
- `vmlinuz-*`
- ... and maybe some others

How can I clean my `/boot` partition? Can I simply (manually) remove these files, or do I need to execute some special procedure?

How can I regenerate my GRUB menu after this `/boot` cleaning?

And is it possible to change `/boot` mounting to a different partition (bigger than 200 MB)? How? Just by changing `/etc/fstab`, or is it more complex problem?

Thanks a lot!